# Displaying a page of all post categories with thumbnails in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need a page in wordpress that automatically displays all categories from a custom post (The post taxonomy is 'portfoliosets') with thumbnails. How would I display these with a thumbnail? Could I put the image source in the category description and have it pull it from that?

Thanks!

Comment: You might get a better response over at [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Wordpress has a codex entry for doing what you want to do.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category#Show_Category_Images)

Unless something has changed recently custom post types were filled into the same category structure as every other category. So you just need to use that codex example to associate certain images with certain categories and then call it to a page, sidebar or wherever. I've seen this done before with favicon style images next to categories.